# Syslog entries getting out of sequence

Tags: syslog, yocto

I have an embedded Linux installation completely self-cross-compiled using Yocto Poky.

Beside the many system services I also have a completely custom application running as headless daemon.

Application is fully written in C++, if it matters.

In order to provide information on what's happening Application routinely calls `syslog()` with appropriate parameters.

This *seems* to work but close inspection of /var/log/messages shows blocks of logs arriving completely out of sequence generating "jumps" back in time of several minutes.

Specifically I have one task that logging (among other things) a sequence number (a strictly incrementing counter, really stupid code) every 100ms.

Time stamps and sequence number appear to be in sync (i.e.: successive sequence numbers are almost exactly 100ms apart drift is completely compatible with multithread latency), but blocks see "scrambled" meaning some large (several minutes worth of logs, about one thousand messages) blocks can come "after" another supposedly "earlier" block.

Please notify me if this description is "not enough" to understand problem.

Here is a small (edited) excerpt:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan 18 20:38:23 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:38:23.501] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [63308] to cache
    Jan 18 20:38:23 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:38:23.601] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [63309] to cache
    Jan 18 20:38:23 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:38:23.701] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [63310] to cache
    Jan 18 20:38:23 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:38:23.804] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
    Jan 18 20:38:23 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:38:23.804] [I] [1794] analyzeState():[CV2X EGO  ] [   1642538303803ms] ID: 0000000000000001 long: 12.365475, lat: 41.939606, heading: 0.000000, speed: 0.000000, s_accur: 0.570000, acc: -0.000000
<<< jump back 224.337 seconds ***
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.467] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61072] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.567] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61073] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.667] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61074] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.767] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61075] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.867] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan 18 20:36:31 sa2150p-nand local0.warn spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:36:31.400] [W] [1795] waitingConnection():No connection attempts for longer than 5000 ms
    Jan 18 20:36:31 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:36:31.400] [D] [1795] onRunBluetoothLoop():No BLE client yet. Retry after 1 second
    Jan 18 20:36:31 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:36:31.488] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [62190] to cache
    Jan 18 20:36:31 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:36:31.588] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
    Jan 18 20:36:31 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:36:31.588] [I] [1794] analyzeState():[CV2X EGO  ] [   1642538191588ms] ID: 0000000000000001 long: 12.365476, lat: 41.939607, heading: 0.000000, speed: 0.000000, s_accur: 0.460000, acc: -0.000000
<<< jump back 224.151 seconds ***
    Jan 18 20:32:47 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:32:47.437] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [59954] to cache
    Jan 18 20:32:47 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:32:47.538] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [59955] to cache
    Jan 18 20:32:47 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:32:47.638] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
    Jan 18 20:32:47 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:32:47.638] [I] [1794] analyzeState():[CV2X EGO  ] [   1642537967638ms] ID: 0000000000000001 long: 12.365478, lat: 41.939608, heading: 0.000000, speed: 0.000000, s_accur: 0.460000, acc: -0.000000
    Jan 18 20:32:47 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:32:47.638] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [59956] to cache
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.166] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61069] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.266] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61070] to cache
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.366] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.367] [I] [1794] analyzeState():[CV2X EGO  ] [   1642538079367ms] ID: 0000000000000001 long: 12.365477, lat: 41.939608, heading: 0.000000, speed: 0.000000, s_accur: 0.450000, acc: -0.000000
    Jan 18 20:34:39 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:34:39.367] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [61071] to cache
<<< jump back 224.036 seconds ***
    Jan 18 20:30:55 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:30:55.331] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [58835] to cache
    Jan 18 20:30:55 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:30:55.431] [I] [1794] analyzeState():Start logging ego and other road users data
    Jan 18 20:30:55 sa2150p-nand local0.info spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:30:55.431] [I] [1794] analyzeState():[CV2X EGO  ] [   1642537855431ms] ID: 0000000000000001 long: 12.365479, lat: 41.939608, heading: 0.000000, speed: 0.000000, s_accur: 0.450000, acc: -0.000000
    Jan 18 20:30:55 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:30:55.431] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [58836] to cache
    Jan 18 20:30:55 sa2150p-nand local0.debug spoke-mw: [2022-01-18 20:30:55.531] [D] [1794] pushBleMessage():Save a STATUS message [58837] to cache
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice messages `Save a STATUS message [61069/70/71] to cache` come much later than `Save a STATUS message [61072/73/..] to cache` while stamps follow quite well sequence.

It *seems* problem is entirely in `syslog()` handling and I also found traces of similar behavior googling around, but I'm unsure if it applies to my case.

Question is: how do I debug such a situation? Having "out-of-sequence logs is "inconvenient" to say the least.

Comment: is it always around 224 seconds?

Comment: Are you logging to a local or remote machine? If you just have a simple shell script, e.g. `typeset -i i=0; while sleep 1 ; do logger -p local0.info "$i" ; : i++ ; done` does it also show out of order messages.

Comment: @Bravo: it varies, but mostly around that figure.

Comment: @icarus: executing the line exactly as-is did *not* produce *any* log; I let it run for over an hour.

Comment: It should produce logs within a second, and then produce additional ones every second.! So first thing to do is get "logger" to write a message to the syslog, then put it into a loop to see if the logging order is correct.